# Has the threefold model (GDS) been documented in an academic publication?

Tags: rpg-theory

The threefold model (not to be confused with the later GNS model) of roleplaying was developed in the previous millenium. [John H. Kim's website](http://www.darkshire.net/jhkim/rpg/theory/threefold/) includes the threefold FAQ and other content related to it.

Has the model been published or summarized in an academic publication?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are a couple of links that look like they might be what you're looking for:

- [Pervasive Play, Immersion and Story: designing *Interference*](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/John_Bichard/publication/221038761_Pervasive_play_immersion_and_story_designing/links/542c0e590cf277d58e8ab3ee.pdf) (first mentioned in section 3.1)
- [Social Conflict in
  Role-Playing Communities:
  An Exploratory Qualitative Study](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/32529729/IJRPissue4bowman.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1506807014&Signature=5gB2Ti%2BzCCUT3HpgnqsV0LtbUDw%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DSocial_Conflict_in_Role-Playing_Communit.pdf) (Readthroughs by more learn-ed scholars than I have stated that this link is not nearly as useful as the first, and the author apparently did not have the best grasp of the theory, so this should not be a primary source.)

You may also want to check out *Immersive Gameplay: Essays on Participatory Media and Role-Playing*, which is tangentially related to your subject.

Comment: A brief summary of your first link would be helpful, as you did for the second link, since "link only" answering is discouraged. (Thanks for the link, that's an interesting article).